# cannot change duration of animated dynamic images in watchOS 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, watchos-2

**UPDATE: I made an XCode 7.3 [sample project displaying the problem](https://github.com/mgiraldo/watchOS-animations-test)**

Question:

I am transferring image frames as `NSData` from the iPhone (Obj-C) to the watch (Swift) via `session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:`. The frames are originally requested by the watch via `session.sendMessage(myMessage, replyHandler:)`. I am converting those images back to PNG with `UIImage(data: frame)` and appending to an array named `images`. I have a `WKInterfaceImage` named `animationImage` where I am able to load the frames and display them like so:

```
let frames = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(images, duration: myDuration)
animationImage.setImage(frames)
animationImage.startAnimating()
```

The problem is that, no matter what value in `myDuration` I always get the same speed (i.e.: super fast):

[image]

These animations display properly in the phone:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

XCode Version 7.3 (7D175) with iOS 9.0 (deployment target)

EDIT:

This is what [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014959-CH1-SW5) say in respect to animating a watchOS `WKInterfaceImage`:

> For animations you generate dynamically, use the
>   `animatedImageWithImages:duration:` method of `UIImage` to assemble your
>   animation in your WatchKit extension, and then set that animation
>   using the `setImage:` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain why startAnimating() of WKInterfaceImage doesn't utilize the duration of the animated image, but it does seem to animate appropriately when using this:

```
animationImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, images.count), duration: myDuration, repeatCount: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set animation duration to imageView like,

```
 animationImage.animationDuration = myDuration
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: watchOS `WKInterfaceImage` does not have that property. I get: `Value of type 'WKInterfaceImage' has no member 'animationDuration'`. per [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014959-CH1-SW5): For animations you generate dynamically, use the `animatedImageWithImages:duration:` method of `UIImage` to assemble your animation in your WatchKit extension, and then set that animation using the `setImage:` method.